# How to apply a function across the columns of several different data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mapply

I have a list containing a lot of dataframes with the same format, and measuring the same variables.

I want to apply the cor function on two of the columns of those dataframes (let's call it "A" and "B") to calculate the correlation between the corresponding variables.

The difficulty I face comes from the fact that I want to calculate the correlation across the values of *all* dataframes for columns A and B, not the correlation between the values of each dataframe separately (something that lapply could do quite easily I guess).

I am therefore not sure how I should proceed to have the cor function calculate the correlation between the A and B columns of all the dataframes in my list. 
I thought of using the mapply function but didn't quite manage to make it work (and I am not even sure this is the best way). I also considered merging the dataframes but there has to be a simpler, more elegant way to apply the function across the list.

Comment: some example data sure would help.

Answer (score 1):

What about just merging just A columns of all data frames c(df1$A,df2$A, ...) and b columns or creating empty A and B vectors, then merging it with the corresponding variables with a loop through all data frames :

```
a <- c(); b <- c();
for (df in dflist){
    a <- c(a,df$A);
    b <- c(b,df$B);
}
```

Hope this helps.